# Recommended way for sharing types between frontend and nodejs graphql

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, frontend

I have started using typescript with graphql on nodejs. But one thing that strikes me is using `gql` from **apollo-server-express**. Is there a way i can use types being used within graphql schema elsewhere.

```js
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';

export const userSchema = gql`
  type User {
    id: String!
    name: String
  }

  type Query {
    getUsers: [User]
  }
`;
```

Now I dont want to create a seperate interface for `User`. And would like a interface as follows to be readily available:

```js
export const usersResolver = {
  Query: {
    getUsers: () => db.get(condition).then(result => {
      const users:Array<User> = [];
    }
  }
};
```

Also, i would like to use these types on frontend as well.

How can this be done.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [GraphQL Code Generator](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator) to automatically generate the types for you based on your schema and queries.